# template, inheritance and polymorphism c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I 'm trying to make a sorting classes like (merge, quick, shell ...etc), and connect them with a bigger parent class  call it Sorter and I m using templates. However when I m trying to connect any of the children classes. And here is a sample of one of the child classes.

```
class MergeSort : public Sorter <class T>
{ //code of the mergesort here }
```

I get these errors

> expected template-name before '<' token
>
> expected '{' before '<' token
>
> expected UNQUALIFIED-ID before '<' token

**EDIT**
This is the code for the Sorter class

```
template <class T>
class Sorter {
 public:
 Sorter(){};
virtual void sort(vector<T>&, int, int) = 0;
};
```

Comment: That's because you have invalid syntax there ... what do you want to use the templates for?

Comment: Learn the syntax before blindly trying to use something

Comment: The particular error you are quoting states that `Sorter` is not a template class.

Comment: @Justin will that is an exercise  for me to learn about the syntax

Comment: @DanielJour i m trying to use the templates because ware asked to sort any numbers float/int anything

Answer (score 1):

Given the latest edit, it is now proven that this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
template<class T>
class MergeSort : public Sorter<T> {
//...
```

Comment: i have template<class T> before it included

Comment: You have it different place. You need to pay attention to details, compiler does not read your mind.